# Mock image for tests in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to use mock-image for creating an object in **Django**.

**tests.py**:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import MyModel
from unittest import mock
from django.core.files import File


class MyModelTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        file_mock = mock.Mock(spec=File, name='FileMock')
        file_mock.name = 'test.png'
        MyModel.objects.create(img=file_mock, name='123',)

    def test_creation(self):
        obj =  MyModel.objects.get(name='123')
        self.assertEqual(obj, '1, 123')
```

But I have an error:

```
TypeError: 'Mock' does not support the buffer interface
```

I use **spec**-argument, how it described in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class).

Why it does not work and how to fix that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

If I use this in **setUp()**:

```
file_mock.read.return_value = b'my_img_data'
```

And then run test, nothing happens:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
```

So, no errors and no running tests.

**UPDATE 1:**

In setUP():

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', size=(50,50), color=(256,0,0))
image_file = BytesIO(image.tostring())
file = InMemoryUploadedFile(image_file, None, 'test.jpg', 'image/jpg', 1024, None)
MyModel.objects.create(img=file, name='123',)
```

And it generates new error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**Traceback:**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_creation ()
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir/graffities/tests.py", line 21, in setUp
    MyModel.objects.create(img=file, name='123',)
  File "dir/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "dir/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 346, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "dir/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 482, in __init__
    signals.post_init.send(sender=self.__class__, instance=self)
  File "dir/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 201, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "dir/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 477, in update_dimension_fields
    width = file.width
  File "dir/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/images.py", line 17, in _get_width
    return self._get_image_dimensions()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.071s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False,)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False,)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path, height_field='height', width_field='width')
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `MagicMock`? I doubt it will help, though. The problem is, that `MyModel.objects.create` requires your mock object returns useful values when it invokes methods like `.read()` on your `file_mock` instance. However, mocks only return mocks in the first place and you'd have to configure the mock's return values and attributes so that `MyModel.objects.create` can work with it.
Depending on what you do with the image file in the database, I would assume a simple `StringIO` instance with arbitrary data might be good enough for providing a stub for an image file.

**Update**

Your `MyModel.objects.create(img=file, name='123',)` requires a [`django.core.files.ImageFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/file/#the-imagefile-class) instance. So you need to pass the `BytesIO` buffer to `ImageFile` and you probably have to *save* the image into the buffer, I'm not sure if the `Image.tostring` would work:

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', size=(50,50), color=(256,0,0))
image_file = BytesIO()
image.save(image_file, 'PNG') # or whatever format you prefer
file = ImageFile(image_file)
MyModel.objects.create(img=file, name='123',)
```

Comment: with **MagicMock** the same problem

Comment: Yep, expected that. So you have to either go through the exercise and setup your mock correctly or try finding a different way of providing a faked image file.

Comment: I use `file_mock.read.return_value` but now the system is "waiting". I have updated the post

Comment: Have you tried using a StringIO instance instead of a Mock? It doesn't look like you need the Mock functionality, like asserts on the method calls, as you don't want to tes the image file.

Comment: I have tried using BytesIO, and I have new error. The post is updated

Comment: In the code snippet, you are still using the file_mock variable, it should be file. If that's not the problem, can you post the traceback.

Comment: I have fixed it and added the traceback

Comment: Can you post your model definition?

Comment: I have posted my model

Comment: In newer django, you should import ```ImageFile``` from ```django.core.files.images```